# Numeric Values Change During Access VBA DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I'm developing a module to automatically import Excel worksheets into an Access table.  The design of the worksheets being imported are identical.  Using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheets imports columns A-O (a mix of text and numeric data) well, however the values for columns P-AD have issues...

Column P and Q represent beginning and ending odometer values with R their elapsed distance.  For example, on the worksheet Vehicle OHS-11 is reported as beginning at 154952, ending at 155636, for an elapsed distance of 684.  The imported record shows as beginning AND ending at 155636, for an elapsed distance of 0.

Columns S-AA just refuse to import at all.  Column AB imports 0 for all records including those with legitimate values (i.e., not null).  Columns AC-AD sporadically import a 0, but many records are blank.  See the figure below:

[image: The following image shows the Excel file (top) against the resulting Access table (bottom). The example record/row is highlighted.]

I've tried to no avail:

- setting the field types in Access
- letting Access create the table from scratch
- DoCmd.RunSavedImport isn't ideal since the source spreadsheets have different names
- a SELECT * INTO will create a new table for each worksheet and I am needing to consolidate the data from all spreadsheets to a single table

It is peculiar that the imports are successful without transfer error tables being created but yet the values are being ignored/swapped.  Should it matter, the cells in columns E-P, R and AB-AD are formulas.

I am using Excel 2016 and Access 2016 on a Windows 10 tablet system.  Here is the code:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Import_New_WS()
'--- Import new worksheets to temporary table

    Dim dbAC As Database
    Dim rsList, rsMonth, rsXfer As Recordset
    Dim strDestPath, strFilePath, strMFRSheetNo, strRange As String

    Set dbAC = CurrentDb()
    Set rsList = dbAC.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [XFER_LIST_ONLY_LATEST_MFR]")
    Set rsMonth = dbAC.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [FP_MO_CAL_MO]")
    'Set rsXfer = dbAC.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [XFER_WS]")

    If rsList.EOF = True Then Exit Sub  'Checks that there are worksheets to process

'--- Delete existing records from MFR consolidation table
    'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    'DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [XFER_WS];"
    'DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'--- Import worksheets into consolidation table
    rsList.MoveFirst
    strMFRSheetNo = Right(CStr(rsList.Fields("MFR_LAST_FP")), 2)
    Do Until rsList.EOF

        rsMonth.FindFirst "FISCAL_MO = " & strMFRSheetNo
        strRange = rsMonth.Fields("WS_NAME") & "!A2:AD" & Format(rsList.Fields("NO_ROWS") + 1, "0")
        strFilePath = rsList.Fields("FILE_PATH")
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "XFER_WS", strFilePath, False, strRange
        strDestPath = "I:\Dept\DCS\MPOOL\Fleet Management Data\MFR\MFR FY " & Mid(CStr(rsList.Fields("MFR_LAST_FP")), 3, 2) & _
            "\" & Mid(strFilePath, 81, Len(strFilePath))
        Debug.Print strDestPath
        'FileCopy strFilePath, strDestPath
        'Kill strFilePath
        rsList.MoveNext

    Loop

    Set dbAC = Nothing
    Set rsList = Nothing
    Set rsXfer = Nothing
    Set rsMonth = Nothing
    DeleteImportErrorTables

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if this is related to your problems, but with `Dim rsList, rsMonth, rsXfer As Recordset` only `rsXfer` is a `Recordset`; everything else is a `Variant`. What you want is `Dim rsList as Recordset, rsMonth as Recordset, ...`

Comment: @xidgel:  Goes to show that you can teach an old dog new tricks.  Alas, this didn't affect the issue, but no sense declaring variables incorrectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and testing multiple strategies to address this issue I simply went back to my original code and somehow it spontaneously started working correctly.  The following day however, it was back to the original anomalous behavior!

Unable to find a solution to the issue I coded around the problem by saving the worksheet as a comma separated value (.csv) file and using DoCmd.TransferText instead.  This strategy circumvented Access' data type guesswork and quickly imported the data into the table.  (As an aside, DoCmd.TransferText doesn't like filenames with more than a single period in them.)